# Predicting the weather with temperature and humidity

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting

I basically want to make this same idea:
[Weather forecast based on pressure, temperature and humidity only (for implementation in Arduino)](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/16366/weather-forecast-based-on-pressure-temperature-and-humidity-only-for-implement#new-answer?newreg=e19b15ff8fa94b949b47b2aa453465f9)
without the pressure sensor.
I have a DS18B20 and a HR202 to do it with, if it is possible.

Comment: Expect the reliability will be quite low without pressure trends, as that's the factor that most indicates pattern changes (lowering pressure meaning incoming fronts/low pressures that bring unsettled weather, rising pressure meaning incoming anticyclones with their settled weather)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest Thanks mate. I was hoping I could make it work without, but now I won't bother trying. I'll get a pressure sensor first.

Comment: Without the pressure sensor, it's basically... when it warms and moistens up, we're probably getting due for a front (especially in active weather seasons)... but at that point you may not be that much better than climate (fronts come every X days on average?)

Comment: Do note though that even the other question had a fourth "instrument"... the wind direction... which can be fairly useful depending on location.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest You say "the other question had a fourth "instrument"... the wind direction... which can be fairly useful depending on location". What do you mean? Are you saying that I need wind direction to predict the weather accurately?

Comment: Their step 3 says "Adjust Z for wind direction: For Northerly winds adjust Z=Z+1
For Southerly winds adjust Z=Z−2" so yes it appears that's a part of it (I was looking back at that answer, no idea how valid their results are... unless I'm making mistakes, the Z table doesn't seem to match up to the math, but it may missing pieces from the archaic website it came from?).  Each tool will have its use.  Pressure is probably most key.  Dewpoint may actually be #2?  At least in my part of the world.  Wind and temperature have their uses too.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/post/What-are-the-correlations-between-climate-weather-variables looks to dig into correlations a bit, may be a useful lead for you to determine what you really want to focus on.